# Supermicro IPMI Bug ? I can't get chassis status via ipmitool

Tags: ipmi

I tried to get the chassis status of client servers via ipmitool.
Command I used is below.

"ipmitool -I lanplus -U ADMIN -P ADMIN -H 192.168.1.xxx chassis power status"

M/B model:X9DRW-7TPF+
FW version:3.0b

But it failed to get status on some servers, massages is below.

"Get Chassis Power Status failed: Insufficient privilege level"

I confirmed this matter was improved after ipmi unit reset is done.

This is ipmi bug?

Answer (score 0):

First you must configure IPMI on host 192.168.1.xxx, then try.
read more here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configuring_IPMI_under_Linux_using_ipmitool